# Woocommerce custom single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am using woocommerce, I edited content-single-product.php file for some customization and I achived it, but I am facing one problem, I want price in product_info_right_cart div, so I added this code:

```
<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 30 ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); ?>
```

But it is showing category, title and description too. Here is my whole code:

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">

<div class="product_info_right">

<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 5); ?>

<?php add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title',10); ?>

<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); ?>

<div class="product_info_right_size_chart">
<a href="#">Click here for size chart</a>
</div>

</div>

<div class="product_info_right_size">

</div>

<div class="product_info_right_cart">

<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 30 ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); ?>

</div>

</div>
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the function `add_action()`, what you are actually doing is telling WordPress to put another function into a queue of functions, which all get run when you then call `do_action()`. What's happening here is that you are adding the `woocommerce_template_single_price` function to the queue of actions that will get run when `do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary')` is called. By the time that you run it in your custom code, it has at least four functions in the queue to process.

You would be better off calling the price function directly here:

```
<div class="product_info_right_cart">

<?php woocommerce_template_single_price(); ?>

</div>
```